# Vue - Cannot set property of undefined in promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have the following Vue file:

```
<template>

  <li class="notifications new">
      <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i> <sup>
          <span class="counter">0</span>
          </sup>
       </a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu notifications-dropdown-menu animated flipInX">
            <ul v-for="notification in notifications" @click="" class="notifications-container">
              <li>
                <div class="img-col">
                  <div class="img" style="background-image: url('assets/faces/3.jpg')"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </li>

</template>

<script>
export default {

    data: function() {
        return {
          notifications: [],
          message: "",
        }
    },

    methods: {

        loadData: function() {
            Vue.http.get('/notifications').then(function(response) {

                console.log(response.data);
                //this.notifications = response.data;
                //this.notifications.push(response.data);

                this.message = "This is a message";

                console.log(this.message);
            });

        },
    },

    mounted() {
        this.loadData();
    },

}

</script>
```

This is compiling just fine, however, when loading up the web page, I get the following error:

> > app.js:1769 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined

I have tried to create another method as well, but had no joy. I literally cannot seem to work out why `this` wouldn't be accessible here.

Comment: Not sure how to use http, as i'm using axios, but you can try
    let that = this;
    Vue.http.get()..{
    
        that.message = "this is a message";
    }

Comment: @GerardoRosciano Hi, No... Still getting the same response :(

Comment: Are you using Vue Resource ?

Comment: It looks like you are using Vue Resource. If you are, then in addition to the answer below, using `this.$http.get` instead of `Vue.http.get` should also solve the problem.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Your context is changing: because you are using the keyword *function*, `this` is inside its scope the anonymous function, not the vue instance.

Use arrow function instead.

```
  loadData: function() {
        Vue.http.get('/notifications').then((response) => {

            console.log(response.data);
            //this.notifications = response.data;
            //this.notifications.push(response.data);

            this.message = "This is a message";

            console.log(this.message);
        });

    },
```

**NB:** You should by the way continue to use the keyword *function* for the top level of your methods (as shown in the example), because otherwise Vue can't bind the vue instance to `this`.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, this seems to be only working for strings. I have an array returning, well object.. `response.data` gives me `Object, Object, Object` whereas `this.notifications = response.data; console.log(this.notifications)` gives `Object {__ob__: Observer}` ??

Comment: Observers are normal things in VueJS, they are attached to each property in data object, and that's one way how vuejs track changes and update them instantly @Phorce 
Suggestion use Vue Devtools chrome extension

Comment: @BelminBedak Is there a tutorial or something where I can achieve what I want to do? I can't seem to find anything on this

Comment: Question is what you want to achieve ? Are you sure that response for the notifications contains any data ? As suggested Vue Devtools would help you a lot, you can exacly see what  each property in data model contains. @Phorce

Comment: @BelminBedak - I want to basically call the API and then get the data and display this in a list. `response.data` contains 3 objects.. 
`0: Object { message: "Welcome to the application"}`
etc..

Comment: @Phorce well then the `this.notifications = response.data;` should do the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142633/discussion-between-phorce-and-belmin-bedak).

Comment: Using an anon function for the top level method was causing my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

One can set `this` to a `const` outside the code block and use that const value to access the class properties.

ie

```
const self = this;

blockMethod(function(data) {
    self.prop = data.val();
})
```

Comment: any more explanation on this?

Answer (score 3):

Use arrow function in promise then you can access 'this' object.

```
loadData: function() {
        Vue.http.get('/notifications').then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            //this.message = 'Something'
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another common reason which I keep bumping into why you'll get this error message.  If you use v-if rather than v-show to hide an item, it won't be in the DOM, won't load initially and won't be available to reference.  I just spent a while working out why this gave the error message above:

```
vm.$refs.refpersonview.Person = ...
```

The reason is that I'd conditionally hidden the component in a v-if block.  Use v-show instead!

Answer (score 1):

**I got results with this structure. I was using axios however I think it will work for your case too.**

```
data(){
 return {
  message = [],
 }
}
methods: {

    loadData() {
        Vue.http.get('/notifications')
        .then(({ data }) => (this.message = data));

        //console.log(this.message);
    },
},

mounted() {
    this.loadData();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
created() {
pipedrive.getAllDeals()
.then(response => {
  // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
  this.posts = response.data
})
.catch(e => {
  this.errors.push(e)
})

// async / await version (created() becomes async created())
//
// try {
//   const response = await axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
//   this.posts = response.data
// } catch (e) {
//   this.errors.push(e)
// }
```

}

Comment: Please explain solution in detail so that others will understand more easily

Comment: You can try arrow functions

Answer (score 0):

We need to define method by using **shorthand** property. For example

```
export default {
  name: "Posts",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchPosts() {
      this.posts = await fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
          .then(x => x.json())
          .catch(e => console.error(e));
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchPosts();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mounted(){
let self = this;
    axios
     .get('API')
     .then(function(resonse){
       console.log(resonse.data.blogs);
       self.blogs = resonse.data.blogs; //Replace this with self
   });
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.