# VueJS + Firebase How do I display an image?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display an image stored in Firebase, but it doesn't work. Currently, nothing is displayed when accessing the page. Where are the mistakes?

[The task]

1. Get id from URL (... /: id)
2. Get image url from Firestore
   　　Document name = id
3. View image

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-col cols="12" md="8" xs="12">
        <img :src="imageurl" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
var db = firebase.firestore();

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imageurl: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const id = this.$route.params.id;

    let cityRef = db.collection("cards").doc(id);
    let getDoc = cityRef.get();
    this.imageurl = getDoc;
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
mounted() {
    const id = this.$route.params.id;
    const cityRef = db.collection("cards").doc(id);

    cityRef.get().then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log(doc.data()) 
            this.imageurl = doc.data().imageurl
        } else {
            console.log('no data')
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //.....
    }
}
```

As explained in [Vue - Cannot set property of undefined in promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613115/vue-cannot-set-property-of-undefined-in-promise), since "you are using the keyword `function`, `this` is inside its scope the anonymous function, not the vue instance".

By using an arrow function you will solve the error.

---

See also the comments I've made on the other answer: by calling the asynchronous [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method you get a Promise that "resolves with a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html) containing the current document contents". On the `DocumentSnapshot` you have to call the [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html#data) method to "retrieve all fields in the document as an Object". Then you have to assign the value of one of those fields, like `this.imageurl = doc.data().imageurl;`

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. And deepened my understanding

Answer (score 0):

`cityRef.get()` returns a promise, so you should get image that way:

```
cityRef.get().then(function(doc) {
 if (doc) {
  console.log(doc.data()) // doc.data() is a response from your query
  this.imageurl = doc.data().imageurl
 } else {
  console.log('no data')
 }
} catch(error) {
...
}
```

There you have [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: Note that `data` is a method and not a property, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html. Therefore your need to do `doc.data()` to "retrieve all fields in the document as an Object". Then you have to assign the value of one of those fields, like `this.imageurl = doc.data().imageurl;`

Comment: Indeed. I've completed the answer. Thank you @RenaudTarnec

Comment: @cccn Thank you. I was able to get the url.
However, `Error getting document TypeError: Cannot set property 'imageurl' of undefined` occurs. I thought `imageurl` could be stored in` data` but it didn't seem

Comment: @kan type console.log(doc.data()) and see what response you get

Comment: @cccn It was confirmed that url was stored in doc.data().

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the syntax to load firebase and to get the doc:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import firebaseConfig from './config/firebase' .  // Your firebase config init settings.
...

db.collection('cards').doc(id)
.get().then(docSnapshot => {
    if (!docSnapshot.exists) return;
    let data = docSnapshot.data()
    // continue your code
});
```

PS: I see you use the new Vuetify 2, great!