# TypeError when trying to assign axios response to data variable in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot set property 'randomWord' of undefined` at this line: `this.randomWord = response.data.word;`

`console.log(response.data.word)` does print out a string.

Vue Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Wordnik Random Word</h2>
    <button class="button" @click="getWord">Random Word</button>
    <p>The random word is: {{ randomWord }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require('axios')

export default {
  name: 'RandomWord',
  data() {
    return {
      randomWord: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getWord() {
      axios.get('https://api.wordnik.com/v4/words.json/randomWord', {
          params: {
            api_key: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
            hasDictionaryDef: true,
            minCorpusCount: 4
          }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data.word);
          this.randomWord = response.data.word;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: I should have been using an arrow function in the first promise.

Change:

```
.then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data.word);
          this.randomWord = response.data.word;
        })
```

to:

```
.then((response) => {
          this.randomWord = response.data.word;
        })
```

A better explanation can be found here: [Vue - Cannot set property of undefined in promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613115/vue-cannot-set-property-of-undefined-in-promise)